# Can't insert user_id and product_id to cart. Laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

When I want to add user_id to `carts` I get this error

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`armytag`.`carts`, CONSTRAINT `carts_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`))
```

The migration went well without this error. I'm using Laravel 5. This is my User.php function:

```
public function cart()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Cart');
}
```

This is Cart.php function:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

This is the function in `CartController`

```
public function add(Request $request, $id)
{
    $cart = new Cart();
    $product = Product::where('id', $id)->first();
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $cart->user_id = $user_id;
    $cart->product_id = $product->id;
    $cart->quantity = $request->quantity;
    $cart->create();
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

I've also set fillable fields in my `Cart.php`

```
protected $fillable = [
    'user_id', 'product_id', 'quantity'
];
```

Also I get this line in the error log:

```
at Connection->runQueryCallback('insert into `carts` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?)'
```

It seems that it is not even trying to insert user_id and product_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you've defined the **cart()** relation incorrectly in your **User** model. **User** is the owning side of **one-to-many** relation so you should call **hasMany()** instead of **belongsTo()**:

```
public function carts()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\Cart');
}
```

Secondly, you need to call **$cart->save()** instead of **$cart->create()**. **save()** will save the existing object, while **create()** will create a new one with values passed as parameters and save it. As no arguments are passed to **create()**, no values other than timestamps are set in the query.

You can also simplify your code and do just:

```
public function add(Request $request, $id)
{
    Cart::create([
      'user_id' => Auth::id(),
      'product_id' => $id,
      'quantity' => $request->quantity
    ]);

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean save cart?

```
$cart->save();
```